# Exactly the same accuracy of different models in the `caret` package resampling output

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret

I am using `R 4.0.4` and package `caret 6.0.89`  for machine learning analysis.
In many of my analysis (with various methods, tunning and preprocessing), results of resampling for the models accuracy comparison(i.e benchmarking) are exactly the same for different algorithms. I've seen this even in ML learning tutorial like "ML mastery with r, by Jason Brownlee":

```
library(caret)



# attach the iris dataset to the environment
data(iris)
# rename the dataset
dataset <- iris

trainControl <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)
metric <- "Accuracy"


# LDA
set.seed(7)
fit.lda <- train(Species~., data=dataset, method="lda", metric=metric,
trControl=trainControl)
# CART
set.seed(7)
fit.cart <- train(Species~., data=dataset, method="rpart", metric=metric,
trControl=trainControl)
# KNN
set.seed(7)
fit.knn <- train(Species~., data=dataset, method="knn", metric=metric,
trControl=trainControl)
# SVM
set.seed(7)
fit.svm <- train(Species~., data=dataset, method="svmRadial", metric=metric,
trControl=trainControl)
# Random Forest
set.seed(7)
fit.rf <- train(Species~., data=dataset, method="rf", metric=metric, trControl=trainControl)

# summarize accuracy of models
results <- resamples(list(lda=fit.lda, cart=fit.cart, knn=fit.knn, svm=fit.svm, rf=fit.rf))


summary(results)
```

I copied the exact code from the book above, and it shows the results as below (simplified):

```
Accuracy
       Min. 1st Qu. Median Mean 3rd
lda   0.9167 0.9375 1.0000 0.9750
cart  0.8333 0.9167 0.9167 0.9417
knn   0.8333 0.9167 1.0000 0.9583
svm   0.8333 0.9167 0.9167 0.9417
rf    0.8333 0.9167 0.9583 0.9500
```

As it is evident from the accuracy result above, `min` accuracy of four models are exactly the same, most notably is that all quartiles of the accuracy of `cart` and `svm` model are exactly the same.

and on my try for the above code:

```
## 
## Call:
## summary.resamples(object = results)
## 
## Models: lda, cart, knn, svm, rf 
## Number of resamples: 10 
## 
## Accuracy 
##           Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu. Max. NA's
## lda  0.9333333 0.9500000 1.0000000 0.9800000 1.0000000    1    0
## cart 0.8666667 0.9333333 0.9333333 0.9400000 0.9833333    1    0
## knn  0.8666667 0.9333333 1.0000000 0.9666667 1.0000000    1    0
## svm  0.8000000 0.9333333 0.9666667 0.9466667 1.0000000    1    0
## rf   0.8666667 0.9333333 0.9666667 0.9600000 1.0000000    1    0
```

Again many accuracy quartiles are the same for different algorithms.

I experienced similar issues many time in my own datasets. Is it a normal finding or a bug?

Comment: Just an artifact of the (very) low number of samples in the iris dataset...

Comment: Actually in one dataset with about 3300 subjects, I get somewhat the same result.

Comment: This is a different story, and probably a different question, which will need details. A "bug" certainly it seems to be not.